# ¿Como hacer una funcion para validar una fecha LocalDate en Java?

Tags: java

Las instrucciones son las siguientes:
Define la clase Fecha, de acuerdo con las siguientes especificaciones, propiedades: día, mes, año. Además de los método públicos setters y getters para cada propiedad, agregue un método especial que permita mostrar en pantalla la fecha usando el formato aaaa/mm/dd, otro método que muestre en pantalla la fecha poniendo el mes con palabras y otro método que verifique si la fecha es válida.

Lo unico que me falta es el ultimo metodo, y no se como hacerlo.
Este es el codigo:

Codigo de la clase Fecha:

```
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.time.LocalDate;

    public class Fecha {
        private String dia;
        private String mes;
        private String año;
        private String fecha;
        private LocalDate fechaUno;
        private String fechaDos;

        public Fecha() {
        }

        public void setDia(String dia) {
            this.dia = dia;
        }
        public void setMes(String mes) {
            this.mes = mes;
        }
        public void setAño(String año) {
            this.año = año;
        }

        public LocalDate getFechaUno() {
            return this.fechaUno;
        }
        public String getFechaDos() {
            return this.fechaDos;
        }

        public void creaFechaUno() {
            this.fecha = this.dia + "/" + this.mes + "/" + this.año; 
            DateTimeFormatter miFormato = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
            this.fechaUno = LocalDate.parse(fecha, miFormato);
        }
        public void creaFechaDos() {
            this.fechaDos = this.fechaUno.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMMM-dd"));
        }
    }
```

Y este es el codigo del MainFecha:

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class MainFecha {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            Fecha ObjetoFecha = new Fecha();

            System.out.println("SISTEMA DE FECHAS");

            System.out.println("Ingrese el año: ");
            ObjetoFecha.setAño(scanner.next());
            System.out.println("Ingrese el mes: ");
            ObjetoFecha.setMes(scanner.next());
            System.out.println("Ingrese el dia: ");
            ObjetoFecha.setDia(scanner.next());

            ObjetoFecha.creaFechaUno();
            System.out.println(ObjetoFecha.getFechaUno());
            ObjetoFecha.creaFechaDos();
            System.out.println(ObjetoFecha.getFechaDos());

            scanner.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define para tí que es "fecha válida", supongo que exista en el calendario gregoriano, pero en todo caso define eso.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con `DateTimeFormatter` y `ResolverStyle`. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649815/5587982) para más detalles.

Comment: con fecha valida se refiere a que si insertas un 30 de febrero, no es una fecha valida, o un mes 13, etc.